# How do I delete R Studio warning messages in the Presentation pane?

Tags: r, rstudio

Everytime I start up R Studio v1.2.1335 I'm greeted with this message in my Presentation pane:

```
C:/Users/user/Dropbox/R-dir/project38/file38.md not found
```

I deleted that file a while ago. How do I delete this warning message?

Comment: You might have to raise it on their github page if you don't get an answer here. They have templated bug reports. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: If you just need RStudio tech support, you're better off asking at https://community.rstudio.com/.